# How to update partial using Ajax call and then render in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, haml

I am not using erb, but using haml instead. So something like:

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @user) %>").appendTo("#users");
```

in http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html is not working.

Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For `HAML`, use *String interpolation* as below:

```
$("#{escape_javascript(render @user)}").appendTo("#users");
```

Comment: should I put this in *.js.haml file? Can I use this just in *.js file?

Comment: *.js.haml file as it should be interpreted by Ruby.